# No matching function for call to strcmp

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and currently am facing an error while using `strcmp`.

I have defined a structure as follows:

```
struct student
{
 string name;
 int roll;
 float marks;
 dob dobi;
 string dobp;
};
student *p;
```

And then, I am passing the pointer inside a function to sort it, like this:

```
void sortData(student *p)
{
 int a=0,b=0;
 for (a=0; a<=arraySize; a++)
 {
    for (b=a; b<=arraySize; b++)
    {
        if( strcmp(p[a].name, p[b].name) > 0 ) //Error
        {
           //sort logic yet to be implemented 
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Can someone please point out the mistake.

**Error Message:**

> No matching function for call to `strcmp`

Comment: Don't use `strcmp()` for `std::string` objects use: `if(p[a].name > p[b].name) { /*...*/}`. And don't loop while `a <= arraySize` that's too far, loop while `a < arraySize`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`strcmp` takes two `const char*`s for input - you need to convert your strings to C-style strings (assuming you're using `std::string`) using `std::string::c_str()`:

```
if (strcmp(p[a].name.c_str(), p[b].name.c_str()) > 0)
//                  ^ Here             ^ and here
```

Comment: `strcmp(p[a].name.c_str(), p[b].name.c_str()) > 0` is semantiacally not equivalent to `p[a].name != p[b].name` and it's meant to be a sort logic so the comparison logic is required to provide a relative order which is not what an inequality check does.

Comment: @Pixelchemist The two expressions can be treated as equal. `strcmp` returns a non-zero integer when the two strings are mismatched and `> 0` converts this to a boolean. This means that in this case, `strcmp` is being used as an inequality check

Comment: No, `strcmp` returns a positive integer if the second argument is first in lexicographical order compared to the first argument and `strcmp(a, b) > 0` is equivalent to `(is b before a in lexographical ordering)` and NOT equivalent to `(is a unqueal b)`. A positive return value has a different meaning from a negative return value and as I said both expression are neither equal nor equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

[`std::strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) takes `const char*` as its parameter, while `std::string` doesn't match directly.

Because you're using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), you can just use [`operator>(std::basic_string)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)

```
if (p[a].name > p[b].name)
```

or use [`std::basic_string::compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare)

```
if (p[a].name.compare(p[b].name) > 0)
```